# Visual C++ - Call a function from a button click method

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I created a Visual C++ project, and made a button in the form. Visual Studio generates this method for a button click event:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
}
```

This code is in the Form1.h file, no problems for now. However, if I try to call a function, in the event method, using other classes, like std::cout (doesn't matter if I define it in the Form1.h file or I #include it from another file), the compiler gives me an error (C2079).

Why does this happen? Please be patient as I am a total noob in Windows GUI programming, thanks in advance to whoever can help.

Comment: Providing some of the source code that is failing would help. However off the top of my head if you are including iostream you might want to replace it with #include <fstream>. From the code above you are using C++/CLI I presume.

Comment: If you use fstream as mentioned also make sure you put this in your source file `using namespace std`

Comment: @MichaelPetch: No, absolutely don't. This is a header file (`Form1.h`).

Comment: Your question title is C++ although I think you must be using C++/CLI (which is the newer Managed C++). If that is the case then you have a completely different problem. Managed services have replaced cin and cout among a bunch of other things. You can see a good description here: http://www.vishnunath.com/cli-programming Look for CLI input output and Console::Write etc. With that being said, I am wondering if you wanted to program in old C++ where things like iostream would work as expected with regular c++ syntax.If so you may wish to generate a C++ project (not C++/CLI and not Managed C++)

Comment: My belief that you aren't using standard unmanaged C++ comes from the carets (^) in your code snippet "(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)"

Comment: Something that is important to know especially if you intend to try GUI development at all in C++/CLI(CLR). What version of Visual Studio are you using? 2010? 2012? 2013? something else? Express version? If it is Visual Studio 2012 or later then I highly recommend not doing GUI development in C++CLI (I'll expand on that later if that is what you are using)

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's an explanation that's part of C2079. It's something like `'identifier' uses undefined class/struct/union 'name'`. This is NOT related to either Windows or GUI programming. The problem is simply that you must have defined the name you're using.

For instance, `std::cout` is defined in `<iostream>` which you probably did not include. BTW, exactly where did you expect `std::cout` to print to? A normal GUI doesn't have a text console.

Comment: I included iostream. I used `std::cout` as an example, I don't need it in my project.

Comment: iostream was deprecated (was part of the the old non standard library) and usage of fstream header is required now

Comment: So try `include <fstream>; using namespace std`    . More information on the deprecated headers and the replacements in VC++ see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984818(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @MichaelPetch: ???? No, `<iostream>` is NOT deprecated at all, it's still valid as ever in C++14. It never was part of any old library either. And `<fstream>` is plain wrong; that defines `std::fstream` and derived classes (**FILE** streams), not `std::cout`.

Comment: We are talking about MS C++ and C++/CLI as well as Unmanaged C++. They have been deprecated on that platform for nearly a decade.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That refers to `<iostream.h>`. Not `<iostream>`.

Comment: Yes and on MS C++ youd could include <iostream.h> or <iostream>. Both are deprecated. Do you do any MS C++ development with the newest compilers? I can tell you iostream works just fine on most platforms that use gcc, clang etc. This is an MS thing.

Comment: I found a tech article that also gives reasons for C2079. First example is related to my comments. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ekhdcxs.aspx

Comment: No, only `<iostream.h>` is deprecated, and your link even states that `<iostream>` is the replacement. As for your new link, that is the exact opposite of what you're trying to claim: It shows that `std::ifstream` (a **FILE** stream )is defined by the (also not deprecated) header `<fstream>`, and not by `<iostream>` (which defines the `std::cout` stream instead.)